# Right way running Getopt::Long::GetOptions in a subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine, getopt-long

Hi I'm using Debian Linux and Perl 5.28 and try to run in a subroutine (method of a class).

The calling part is produced by a toolkit object $TK:

```perl
# Usage sugar: help, man and version for the CLI
my $IS_MAN;  # Flag show man page
my $IS_HELP; # Flag show help page
my $IS_VER;  # Flag show version

# Variables for the CLI
my $OUTPUT;    # IPC Variable to manage an operation status
my $RESPONSE;  # IPC Variable to state a response type INFO, WARN, ERROR...
my $COMMAND;   # Current command to address a routine in this tool
my $BCK_NAME;  # Name to manage the backup session under an ID
my $ARC_SIZE;  # Size of the expected archive size
my $TAPE_SIZE; # Size of the expected tape volume
my $WORK_PATH; # Work path canonical usually given by $ENV{TOOL_BACKUP}

# Read the param's into vars
$TK->parseCommandline(
    {            
    "command|c=s"      => \$COMMAND,
    "help|h"           => \$IS_HELP,
    "man|m"            => \$IS_MAN,
    "version|v"        => \$IS_VER,
    "output|o=s"       => \$OUTPUT,
    "response|r=s"     => \$RESPONSE,
    "backup-name|B=s"  => \$BCK_NAME,
    'tape-size|T=s'    => \$TAPE_SIZE,
    'archive-size|A=s' => \$ARC_SIZE,
    'work-path|W=s'    => \$WORK_PATH,
   } 
);
```

The class $TK shall run the commandline parser (method) with well defined exit procedure for errors and a canocical output. The error catching works good. But I can't get the CLI parameter with a valid switch.

```perl
sub parseCommandline($$) {
    my ($self, $opt) = @_;

    # Catch errors thrown by GetOptions
    my $sigFun = $SIG{__WARN__};
    my @errs =();
    $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
        my $msg = shift;
        chomp($msg);
        push( @errs, $msg );
     };

    # Dump the predefined switches
    print Dumper($opt);

    # Get the options
    GetOptions( $opt)
        or exitFatalConfig($self,
            join( ";\n", @errs ) . "!");

    # Restore the warnings
    $SIG{__WARN__} = $sigFun;

    # Go into init-runtime mode
    $self->runtime->{+KEY_COMMAND} = 'init-runtime';
}
```

The method flags always an error despite of having the option -o enabled.

```
IO.MAGIC:  TEST.TOOL.V1.2
IO.COMMAND:  ./Test-App -o TEST.VARIABLE
$VAR1 = {
          'tape-size|T=s' => \undef,
          'backup-name|B=s' => \undef,
          'output|o=s' => \undef,   <------ HERE 
          'work-path|W=s' => \undef,
          'response|r=s' => \undef,
          'help|h' => \undef,
          'man|m' => \undef,
          'version|v' => \undef,
          'command|c=s' => \undef,
          'archive-size|A=s' => \undef
        };
EOF.TEST.TOOL.V1.2

STATUS: FAILED
  PROGRAM:  ./Test-App
  MESSAGE:  Unknown option: o!
EOF.STATUS
```

What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2):

```perl
GetOptions( $opt)
```

should be

```perl
GetOptions(%$opt)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, so simple. Is the topic covered in the POD? I only found something in '*Parsing options from an arbitrary array*' that mentions `$ret = GetOptions(\%opts, ... );` in terms of argument shifting, as a hint for the nature of $opts.

Comment: Re "*Is the topic covered in the POD?*", It's all over the docs. About the first thing you see in the docs is `GetOptions("length=i" => \$length, "file=s" => \$data, "verbose" => \$verbose)`. But that's not what you were passing. Instead of passing something like this, you were passing a single scalar (a ref to a hash).

Comment: By passing a hash ref as the first (and only) argument, you were using the approach documented under "Storing options values in a hash" (`GetOptions(\%h, 'length=i', "file=s", "verbose")`), except you followed the hash ref with exactly zero definitions of options. That's why it didn't recognized `-o`.